# elasticsearch data storage design

Tags: elasticsearch, datadesign

I have sensor data from devices. looks like:
    `[status:1,temperature:20,date:20160101]`
    `[status:1,temperature:21,date:20160101]`
    `[status:1,temperature:21,date:20160101]`
    `[status:1,temperature:21,date:20160101]`
    `[status:2,temperature:5,date:20160101]`
    `[status:2,temperature:5,date:20160101]`
    `[status:2,temperature:5,date:20160101]`
    `[status:1,temperature:21,date:20160101]`
    `[status:1,temperature:21,date:20160101]`

also there is timestamp field in each data, I prepare to storage them to elasticsearch, I have 2 requirements

1.query temperature list in different status and do the pagination
    `[status:1,temperature[20,21,21,21]]`
    `[status:2,temperature[5,5,5]]`
    `[status:1,temperature[21,21]]`

2. query average temperature per day
   `avgTemperature(date)`

is there any proper way to storage these data in es? or provide some advices about this case.

Comment: in point 1 you defined the structure, you are not strict about the structure?. take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html. You can set status in parent document and child documents can have temperature and date

Comment: thanks for your apply, I checked ES's parent-child, but still refused if I put temperature data as child then should specify parentID(status_id) and keep status_id distinctly, one big issue was ES didn't support parent aggregation, how can I query temperature per day?